# Iterate through pairs of rows with a condition on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a client table like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0g1j.jpg) and I need a query to get the pairs of clients that live in the same city (pairs can't be represented more than once). I'm totally lost on this one, any help or guidance would be very much appriciated
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of query is handled using a self-join:

```
select t1.nomC, t2.nomC, t1.ville
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.ville = t2.ville and t1.nomC < t2.nomC;
```